# Why is the email atachment i sent by BizTalk "body.csv" in OUTLOOK 2016?

Tags: email, biztalk, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

I created a simple interface that send an email. I have set the filename by

```
msg_out_renamed(MIME.FileName) = FileName;
```

This works fine in my outlook 2013, it shows as `"client_inv_20160909090658.csv"`.

But the receipient who uses Outlook 2016 has it show up as "**body.csv**". When he decides to save the attachment the filename in the save as dialog is  `"client_inv_20160909090658.csv"`.

Why does this happen and is there a way i can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917794/how-set-attachment-name-to-show-properly-in-outlook?noredirect=1#comment74884803_43917794

Comment: @NealWalters We unfortunatly didn't solve this. I hope you get a working solution on your question.

Comment: Anybody found an answer for this? I'm having the same issue for the moment.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer I've made a complete answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917794/how-set-attachment-name-to-show-properly-in-outlook/52426481#52426481

Answer (score 1):

Change the context property **MIME.FileName** for the **part** of your **attachment** as well.

In an orchestration: (note the *".part"* code)

```
Message.part(MIME.FileName) = "NewFileName.txt";
```

In a pipeline component: (note the *".BodyPart"* code)

```
pInMsg.BodyPart.PartProperties.Write("FileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", "NewFileName.txt");
```

Unfortunately we cannot see these context properties via the Message details screen in the BizTalk console. Attach a debugger to inspect these values.

Comment: Trying to add msg_out_renamed.part(MIME.FileName) = FileName; to the Orchestration (in the same expresion block as where is set the non part filename) gives me an invalid expression error. I haven't tried the pipeline yet but this is something that has to be done even for non multipart messages?