# Body part is sent as attachment in biztalk dynamic SMTP Send port

Tags: c#, email, dynamic, smtp, biztalk

Email is getting Body in attachment along with attachment using biztalk SMTP dynamic send port.

Using C# helper class as:

```
namespace OutputStringContent
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SMTPTestHelper
    {
        public static XLANGMessage AttachStreamToSmtpMessage(XLANGMessage xlangMsg, String strAttach)
        {
            byte[] memBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strAttach);
            IStreamFactory streamFactory = new BinaryStreamFactory(new MemoryStream(memBuffer));
            xlangMsg.AddPart(streamFactory, "AttachedMessage");
            xlangMsg["AttachedMessage"].SetPartProperty(typeof(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType), "text/plain; name=text.txt");

            return xlangMsg;
        }
    }
}
```

In Message Assignment shape in Orchestration:

> ```
> msgSendEmail.MessagePart_1 = new OutputStringContent.RawString(msgEmail.EmailBody);
> msgSendEmail.MessagePart_1(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType) = "text/plain";
> msgSendEmail = OutputStringContent.SMTPTestHelper.AttachStreamToSmtpMessage(msgSendEmail,msgEmail.EmailAttachements);
>
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.From) = msgEmail.EmailFrom;
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.SMTPTo) = msgEmail.EmailTo;
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.Subject) = msgEmail.EmailSubject;
> //msgSendEmail(SMTP.EmailBodyText) = msgEmail.EmailBody;
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.EmailBodyTextCharset) = "UTF-8";
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2;
>
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.SMTPHost) = "smtp1.tucaas.com";
> msgSendEmail(SMTP.SMTPAuthenticate) = 0;
>
> Port_SendEmail(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "mailto:"+msgEmail.EmailTo;
> ```

Expected Result : Email should not have the body as attachment.

Comment: why are you using 2 message parts?  msgSendEmail(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2;

Comment: as I need to send Attachments in Email.

Comment: seems you only have 1 attachment. so it should be msgSendEmail(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 1;

Comment: @Code_ABC I've made a pretty extensive answer in an older question related to attachments in dynamic send ports which could help you out. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917794/how-set-attachment-name-to-show-properly-in-outlook/52426481#52426481

Answer (score 0):

Add a "MIME/SMIME encoder" pipeline component to your send port pipeline and set "send body part as attachment" property to "False". That[image] should do the trick.