# BizTalk - Setting email contentType causes error: There is an error in XML document (1, 1)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

When I try to set the Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType in a BizTalk orchestration, I get an XML error (regardless of whether I use "text/plain" or "text/xml".  I'm using a dynamic send port with the PassThru pipeline.

```
msg_Email.BodyPart = new Ledger6002.Component.RawString("See attached email. Method 2"); 
msg_Email.AttachmentPart = msg_Ledger6002_File_XmlDoc;

// Set the filename as it should display on the attachment in the email 
// (drop the path, just the filename/extension)
attachmentName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(
                       msg_Ledger6002_File_XmlDoc(FILE.ReceivedFileName));

msg_Email.AttachmentPart(MIME.FileName) =  attachmentName; 

msg_Email.BodyPart(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType) = "text/plain";
msg_Email.AttachmentPart(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.ContentType) = "text/plain";
```

Causes this error:

```
xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'Ledger6002.Logic.Ledger6002_Process_File(9eb6993c-87d0-7bf0-b0bf-e1f684000af2)'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: 216e4bac-0f22-4e06-9e61-2ef46051c991
Shape name: msg_Email
ShapeId: e7ce3f54-0558-4756-a7e4-e3800721178f
Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 55
Inner exception: There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
        
Exception type: InvalidOperationException
Source: System.Xml
Target Site: System.Object Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader, System.String, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.GetObject(Type t)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value._prepareForWrite(PreferredValueRepresentation pvr)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ValueTable.PrepareForWrite(ValueToken& vt, PreferredValueRepresentation pvr)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.PrepareForWrite(PreferredValueRepresentation pvr)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.SetPartProperty(Type propType, Object val)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.SetPropertyValue(Type propType, Object val)
   at Ledger6002.Logic.Ledger6002_Process_File.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
Additional error information:

        Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
        
Exception type: XmlException
Source: System.Xml
Target Site: Void Throw(System.Exception)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderObject.Read2_anyType()
```

msg_email is a multipart message, with two parts: bodyPart and attachmentPart, both defined as a RawString custom class.

What could be causing this error? Do I need a pipeline that uses the MIME/Encoder?

I'm now at a different client, trying a response to a 2017 question (but using an orchestration instead of a pipeline): [How Set Attachment Name to Show Properly in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917794/how-set-attachment-name-to-show-properly-in-outlook/52426481)

When I comment out the two lines that set the contentType, I get an email, but same problem as referenced in the 2017 post above.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing at least 2 things:

- Use the SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments setting and set it on "2"
- Use the SMTP.EmailBodyTextCharset and set it on "UTF-8"

Comment: I have many variations where I have tried those and others. 
I put all my SMTP setting in a different shape where I set subject, to, from etc...  But I will try with those and report back.  But the question is why ContentType gives the error. Maybe you are answering my older more general question on why the email shows only body.txt?

Comment: New Error: The part 'AttachmentPart' of message 'msg_Email' contained a null value at the end of the construct block.
The number of permutations of all these SMTP parameters is very high, and they all have to be exact for this to work.  I find sending via C# is super easy, but trying to do it "the BizTalk way".

Comment: The program compiles with either msg_Email(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2;  or 
msg_Email,AttachmentPart(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2; 
Which one should be used in my case?

Comment: Use msg_Email(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2

Comment: Tried that, and got the new error above.  The part 'AttachmentPart' of message 'msg_Email' contained a null value at the end of the construct block.  But then I took out that line of code, and still got that error.  I keep changing various parms over and over, trying and trying.  I thought I had Dynamic working except the body said body.txt instead of the filename I wanted.  I have also have branches that try "Specify later" ports where I override.

Comment: are you sure you constructed AttachmentPart first before setting the properties?

Comment: Also try a hard coded value for attachmentName to make sure it has a value. Also make sure in your multi-part message, that the attachment is the 2nd part in your orchestration message (where you define it).

Comment: Part 1 - Really appreciate your ideas. 1st, does the order of the message parts in the message part type really matter?  I notice that if I close and re-open the orchestration, they re-sort alphabetically?  I have tried both setting my BodyPart's property :BodyPart=True and the other ways around, AttachmentPart's property: BodyPart=True. It looks like it only allows one of the two to have BodyPart=True.  I renamed AttachmentPart to PartAttachment to be second, but I can't imagine the order would really matter.   More in part2....

Comment: Part2 - I changed to this: msg_Email.PartAttachment = new SBA.Ledger6002.Component.RawString("Test Text"); 

Both my BodyPart and PartAttachment are RawString.  Now I get yet another error: "A failure was encountered while transmiting the message". A message sent to adapter "SMTP" on send port "Ledger6002.Logic_1.0.0.0_SBA.Ledger6002.Logic.Ledger6002_Process_File_SMTP_Dyn_Email_29e2dfe767e45251" with URI "xxx.xxx.yyy@gov" is suspended. 
 Error details: Unknown Error Description

Comment: I think you almost got it, try adding the MIME/SMIME encoder at the encoding pipeline component part

Comment: Thanks, Got it!  I've always just called C# because the SMTP adapter has so many hidden tricks.

Comment: Got email with the dummy text, posted separate question for getting my CSV to come through, still getting null... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509140/biztalk-smtp-the-part-partattachment-of-message-msg-email-contained-a-null-v